# Saving NSMutableArray to iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

In the Simulator I can save an NSMutableArray to a file and read it back with the following code:

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"RiskValues"]){  // If file exists open into table
        NSLog(@"Risk Values File Exists");
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RiskValues", documentsDirectory];
        gRiskValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];
        gRiskValuesAlreadyInitialised   = YES;
        } else {    
        NSLog(@"Can't find RiskValues file, so initialising gRiskValues table");            
        Do something else .......
        }
```

This doesn't work on the device. I have tried to locate the file using the following but it still doesn't work:

```
                    NSString *fullFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent@"RiskValues"];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Great answers from everyone. I have resolved the file path and existence issues at a stroke.  Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide absolute path here:

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"RiskValues"])
```

So it must look like this:

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"RiskValues"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: fullFileName]){  // If file exists open into table
        NSLog(@"Risk Values File Exists");
        gRiskValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];
        gRiskValuesAlreadyInitialised   = YES;
        } else {    
        NSLog(@"Can't find RiskValues file, so initialising gRiskValues table");            
        Do something else .......
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RiskValues", documentsDirectory];
```

this line, you're not creating your full path string right. what you should do is

```
NSString *fullFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"RiskValues"];
```

also this check

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"RiskValues"])
```

Will never pass on iOS as it is not a full path to any place you are allowed to write at in your sandbox. I suppose it works on the simulator because on the mac it's looking up relatively to the HD root (or something, not sure how the mac file system works :) ), but on the iOS you're going to have to give it a path to a file/directory in your documents (maybe by appending @"RiskValues" to it or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

1) `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"RiskValues", documentsDirectory]` is just `@"RiskValues"`. So this name points to file in application's directory.

2) `[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"RiskValues"]` searches for file in application directory. It's available for read/write in simulator (it's in your computer file system after all) but it's read-only on device.

BTW ([NSFileManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3a))

> Attempting to predicate behavior based
>   on the current state of the file
>   system or a particular file on the
>   file system is not recommended. Doing
>   so can cause odd behavior in the case
>   of file system race conditions. It's
>   far better to attempt an operation
>   (such as loading a file or creating a
>   directory), check for errors, and
>   handle any error gracefully than it is
>   to try to figure out ahead of time
>   whether the operation will succeed.

Solution:

1) Do not check file presence. Just try to make dictionary with `initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`

2) You want it to be in documents directory so construct path like this

```
[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"RiskValues"];
```